# ADBannerView.h:20:8: Redefinition of 'NSString' as different kind of symbol

Tags: ios6, ios7, nsstring, redefinition, adbannerview

I get this error:

```
 Redefinition of 'NSString' as different kind of symbol

at line:

extern NSString * const ADErrorDomain;

in ADBannerView.h
```

It used to work, has it something to do with Switching SDKs? from ios6 to ios7?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in header, look at your header files in your code.

I had an erroneous int which I must have type in my code.